# org-archive-subtree: Invalid ‘org-archive-location’ Mark set

Tags: org-mode, archive-mode

I get this when I try to archive a subtree. My config reads

```
(setq org-archive-location "~/mega/org/archive.org")
```

which does exist. So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **C-h v** and type in *org-archive-location* you will see the documentation.
There you can see the original value ("%s_archive::") and a few examples

```
"~/org/archive.org::" , "::* Archived Tasks" or "~/org/archive.org::* From %s"
```

Now you will probably already realize that you need the double colon in your string.

Syntax seems to be the following:

```
"/path/::Heading"
```

So your solution should be:

```
(setq org-archive-location "~/mega/org/archive.org::")
```

Comment: thank you that worked. Did that change in emacs 26? it used to work under 25 if I remember correctly

Comment: I have no idea as i have started using emacs with version 26.2